# Vagrant: port forwarding is working oddly

Tags: vagrant

I've got this in my Vagrantfile:

```
web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.20"
web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

but on my Mac Host I'm able to access the `web` VM using `192.168.33.20:80` but NOT `192.168.33.20:8080`.

Why is this not working as expected?

Answer (score 4):

vagrant [Port forwarding](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) is used if you dont have static IP and you want to reach a specific port for a process bound to this specific port running on the VM, so you will access it using `http://localhost:8080` and it will forward to port 80 on the VM.

When you have a static IP, you reach directly the network interface to this VM so it tries to connect you on the port 8080 directly in the VM, if you dont have anything running there, it wont show up.

Rules: **if you use static IP (wether private or public network) you dont need port forwarding**